# Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch (Iphone App)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Im trying to make an Iphone app for my coursework and im getting the error

```
2015-06-26 00:41:31.721 My Movies[3313:6954045] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

Im currently running off Xcode 6.3.2 (6D2105)

This is what my AppDelegate.m finish launching options section looks like

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    // Create Film TableView and add it to Navigation Controller, then add Nav'Controller to Window
    FilmTableTableViewController *vc = [[FilmTableTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [[self window] addSubview:[navController view]];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add the navcontroller as a subview.
Replace that with

```
// [[self window] addSubview:[navController view]];
[self.window setRootViewController:navController];
```